# UITableView only shows data from JSON when I scroll up and down

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

UITableView only shows data from JSON array when I scroll up and down. When I load the table view it shows cells but they are blank and as I scroll up and down it then starts showing the data.

How do I show the cells with data without scrolling?

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    if (request.responseStatusCode == 400) {
        NSLog( @"Code already used");

    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 403) {
        NSLog( @"Code already used");

    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        const char *convert = [response UTF8String];
        NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
        responseArray  = [responseString JSONValue];
        Nrows = [responseArray count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"allfeeds"];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"allfeeds2"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting the request asynchronously (non-blocking)

```
[request startAsynchronously];
```

Try doing it synchronously (blocking)

```
[request startSynchronously];
```

Comment: its magicly Done! :) Thanks alot  its working.. now              [requeststartSynchronously];    has worked out

Answer (score 2):

When you finish your request and you set the array, make sure to call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

For performance and animation purposes, table views don't reload their data when the source changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and got my answer at the Apple's Developer Forums a while ago, this solved my problem:

> From what you've described, I'd guess the problem is more likely to be in cellForRowAtIndexPath or wherever you do the actual configuration of a cell than in the code you've posted.  A problem like yours can happen when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier gives you back an existing cell, but you don't reset its existing state completely.

The full question and answers can be found here (requires login): https://devforums.apple.com/message/502483#502483

Comment: Can you please tell me how I gona reset its state?

Comment: You have to change EVERY bit of information at the cell. Imagine you have a title, a subtitle and a `accessoryType.UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` so for every cell that you draw you have to modify those three, even if one of them is the same for all the cells, you just rewrite it.

Comment: but in my case I am getting NSArray from json, and I have two textfields in each cell, like text label and detail text.

Comment: NSString* CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
    
    
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 
 if(cell == nil){
  
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

Answer (score 0):

These problems are usually caused by the UITableView cache, that dequeues his available cached UITableViewCell with the same CellIdentifier (in your case - @"Cell").

Try creating a cell identifier for each and everyone of your table's cells. You can create this variance using the NSIndexPath param in the following way :

```
NSString* cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
```

That of course, under the assumption you're not changing the content of your cells after you load the data.

Comment: I did , this but no luck, when i load the table view its showing blank and as scroll it starts showing me the values and if i go up again it starts showing me the rest of ones, I am loading it asyncronously. Please recomend somthing

Comment: As i scroll down its statrd showing me the values but it loads blank.